# Си - Удалить чётные строки 2-мерной матрицы

Tags: c

Есть двумерная матрица(количество строк и столбцов задает пользователь), заполненная случайными числами. Программа должна удалить все чётные строки с исходной матрицы и вывести результирующую матрицу в консоль. Выделил блок памяти под матрицу M на N с помощью функции malloc(). Дальше как по мне нужно поднять нечётные строки вверх в матрице, то есть чтобы сразу шли нечетные, а потом четные строки. А потом сузить выделяемый блок памяти до (M/2)*N элементов с помощью функции realloc(), но не знаю как это реализовать.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
int *p, i, j;
int M, N;
int temp;

printf("Input the amount of raws(non-negative integer)\n");
scanf_s("%d", &M);
printf("Input the amount of columns(non-negative integer)\n");
scanf_s("%d", &N);
if ((p = (int*)malloc(M*N * sizeof(int))) == 0) {
    puts("Memory allocation error!!!");
    exit(1);
}
puts("Input array:\n");
for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        p[i * N + j] = rand() % (N * M);
        printf("%8d ", p[i * N + j]);
    }
    puts("\n");
}

puts("Addresses of elements in the array\n");
for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        printf("%13u ", &p[i * N + j]);
    }
    puts("\n");
}

_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Может, четные и нечетные?...

Comment: да..................

Comment: Строки с номерами 2N+1 переносите в строки с номерами N. После чего *просто забудьте* о наличии лишних строк - к чему вам `realloc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void putMat(int* p, unsigned int Rows, unsigned int Cols)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Rows; i++) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < Cols; j++) {
            printf("%8d ", p[i*Cols + j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int Rows, Cols;;

    printf("Rows: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &Rows);

    printf("Columns: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &Cols);

    int * p;

    if ((p = (int*)malloc(Rows*Cols*sizeof(int))) == 0)
    {
        puts("Memory allocation error!!!");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < Cols; j++)
        {
            p[i*Cols + j] = rand()%(Rows*Cols);
        }
    }


    puts("Input array:\n");
    putMat(p,Rows,Cols);

    for(unsigned int row = 1; row < Rows; row += 2)
    {
        unsigned int newRow = (row-1)/2;
        for(unsigned int col = 0; col < Cols; ++col)
            p[newRow*Cols+col] = p[row*Cols+col];
    }

    puts("New array:\n");
    putMat(p,(Rows+1)/2,Cols);

    Rows = (Rows+1)/2;

    int * t = realloc(p, Rows*Cols*sizeof(int));
    if (t == 0)
    {
        puts("Memory allocation error!!!");
        exit(1);
    }
    p = t;

    puts("After realloc:\n");
    putMat(p,Rows,Cols);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем менять саму матрицу? Просто выводить в консоль строки с парными номерами и все

Comment: Какой смысл оформлять комментарий как ответ?

Comment: Это не комментарий, это ответ

Comment: @Akina: если с  результирующей матрицей ничего кроме вывода в консоль не предполагается делать (формулировка в вопросе), то ответ: «просто выводите чётные строки» имеет право на существование (как дополнение к другим).